Prove that if a subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R^n$ contains a strongly positive vector, then $S$ has a basis of strongly positive vectors.
A vector $v= (a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ is called strongly positive if $a_i>0$ for all # $i=1,...,n $
a) Suppose that is $v$ is strongly positive. Show that any vector that is “close enough” to $v$ is also strongly positive. (Formulate carefully what “close enough” should mean.)
b) Prove that if a subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R^n$ contains a strongly positive vector,
then $S$ has a basis of strongly positive vectors.
For a):
I formulate "close enough" like this: Let $u=(b_1,...,b_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ we said that $u$ is close enough to $v$ if
$$ (\sum_{i=1}^n |b_i-a_i|^2 )^{1/2} < \frac{a}{2} $$
Where $a= \min\{a_i: 1\le i\le n \}$.
So if $u$ is close enough to $v$ then
$ \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i-a_i|^2  < \frac{a^2}{4} \Rightarrow |b_i-a_i| < \frac{a}{2} 
 \text{  }(\forall i=1,...,n) $
If $b_i >a_i \Rightarrow b_i >a_i >0$
If $b_i <a_i \Rightarrow |b_i-a_i| = a_i-b_i < \frac{a}{2} \le \frac{a_i}{2} \Rightarrow b_i \ge \frac{a_i}{2} >0 $
Then $u$ is strongly positive.
For b)
Since $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $boy(\mathbb R^n) =n$ then there is a basis $B$ of $S$ such that $B=\{b_1,...,b_m\} $ Here $m \le n $.
Let $v=(a_1,...,a_n) \in S$ is a strongly positive vector.
I tried to prove b) by using this stronglr vector and a) But I couldn't. I find a solution in the internet by using $\{v+ r.b_1,...,v+ r.b_m\}$ For some $r>0$.
But I can't see that if it is a linear independent set or if it is spaining $S$.
I tried to prove that set is a linear independent set like this:
Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m \in \mathbb R$ and
$$ \alpha_1(v+rb_1)+...+\alpha_m(v+rb_m)=(0,...,0) $$
Since $v \in S $ and $ B$ is a basis for $S$
$v= \beta_1 b_1 +...+\beta_m b_m $ Where $\beta_1,...,\beta_m \in \mathbb R $
So
$$ \alpha_1(\beta_1 b_1 +...+\beta_m b_m +rb_1)+...+\alpha_m(\beta_1 b_1 +...+\beta_m b_m+rb_m)=0_{\mathbb R^n}$$
$$\Rightarrow (\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_1 b_1+...+(\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_m b_m+ r(\alpha_1 b_1+...+\alpha_mb_m)=0_{\mathbb R^n}$$
$$\Rightarrow ((\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_1+r \alpha_1) b_1+...+((\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_m+r \alpha_m) b_m=0_{\mathbb R^n}$$
$$\Rightarrow (\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_1+r \alpha_1=0\\
\vdots\\
(\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)\beta_m+r \alpha_m=0$$
$$\Rightarrow  (\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)(\beta_1 +...+\beta_m)+r(\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow  (\alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m)(\beta_1 +...+\beta_m+r)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow  \alpha_1 +...+\alpha_m=0 \vee \beta_1 +...+\beta_m+r=0$$
But I can't get any thing from this?

For part a just some idea of open ball in R^n for a positive vector. For part b, induction may work well on $\dim S$. (Start at $\dim S=1$)

@AngaeMT can you explain more?How Can I use induction here?

for part (b): since you are working over $\mathbb R^n$ why not write your basis for the subspace as matrix $\mathbf B$ with $\mathbf b_k := b_k + t \cdot v$.  Now compute $\det\big(\mathbf B^T \mathbf B\big)$ -- you know it is a polynomial that is non-zero  when $t=0$ so it is non-zero for all but finitely many $t$ (so just pick $t$ large enough).

Show that for any vector $v$ (strongly positive or not) and any $r > 0$, that ${v+rb_1, v+ rb_2, \dots, v + rb_n}$ is also a basis for $\Bbb R^n$. Then choose $v$ to be your strongly positive (i.e. "first $2^n$-tant") vector and $r$ small enough for the vectors to be inside the ball around $v$.

@PaulSinclair I tried to prove this set is a basis. But I can't. I can't see how it is spaining $\mathbb R^n$ or how it is linearly independent set. I tried to use the definitions but I can't get anything.

@PaulSinclair I write how I tried to prove that this set is linearly independent in my OP.

Show first the case when $v = 0$ (which is trivial). Then show the case when $r = 1$ (and $v \ne -b_i$ for any $i$ - a restriction I forgot to include above). For that, note that since ${b_i}_i$ is a basis, so is ${b_1, b_2-b_1,b_3-b_1, \dots, b_n-b_1}$, Also note that $v$ itself is some linear combination of the $b_i$.

I also suggest showing that the set spans $\Bbb R^n$ rather than trying to show directly that it is linearly independent. Because the dimension of the space is $n$ and there are $n$ vectors in the set, linear independence follows.

@PaulSinclair for the first comment $v \neq 0$ because $v$ is strongly positive. Also I can't understand why I have to prove this for $r=1$ especially.  For the second comment, I take $B$ as a basis for $S$ not for $\mathbb R^n$ So it must to be  $Card(B)=m \le n$. isn't this true?

The statement is true for any $v$ and any $r$ and any basis $B={b_i : i = 1,\dots,n}$ except when $r = 0$, or $v=-rb_i$ for some $i$ (in which case one of the vectors would be $0$). It is most easily proven by breaking it up into the two cases: (1) if $B$ is a basis and $r \ne 0$, then $rB$ is a basis (i.e., treat $v = 0$). (2) if $B$ is a basis and $-v\notin B$, then $v + B$ is a basis (i.e. treat $r=1$). Combining those gives the full result. This is a far easier proof than getting in a tizzy that your particular application (which can come in after this proof) involves a non-zero $v$.

As for the other - sorry, make that "show the set spans $S$ and has $m$ vectors." After i wrote the original comment, I did many other things and had to review the question for my later replies. I noted the $b_i$ in part (a) which formed a basis for $\Bbb R^n$, not $S$, and went forward with it.

@PaulSinclair I proved 1) but I have problem with $v+B$. I proved that $v+B$ spans $S$ But I can't prove that it is linear independent. I have a problem like that problem in OP. I found that $\alpha_1\beta_i +.\alpha_2\beta_i..+ \alpha_m \beta_i+\alpha_i=0$ for any $i \in {1,...,m}$ But I can't continue

If $v + B$ is not linearly independent, then you can write one of its vectors as a combination of the others, and thus every element of $S$ can be written in terms of a set of $m-1$ vectors. This includes the $m$ vectors of $B$, meaning that they were not linearly independent either, contradicting that $B$ is a basis.

@PaulSinclair I got it. Thank you so much :)
